# Как отличить страницу от картинки в $_SERVER?

Tags: php

Через php нужно определить из переменной $_SERVER, что загружена именно страница, а не картинка.
Как это можно сделать?
т.е. не важно картинка или css,img,js, пусть любой другой элемент страницы, но нужно различить что этот get запрос относится к странице.
т.е. чтобы в инспекторе кода в браузере network, раздел type=document

Comment: В HTTP-заголовке `Accept` браузер прописывает, какие типы данных он желает получить в ответе

Comment: А у тебя пхп отдает css,img и js?